# AJAX HTML PHP question

Tags: php, html, ajax

**This is my scripts.js**

```
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","inputProcess.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<form>
  Type your name here : <input type="text" onkeypress="showHint(this.value)" name="name" />
</form>
```

**This is my PHP file**

```
<?php

  $q = $_GET['q'];
$dbc=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('input_oop') or die (mysql_error());

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users set name = '".$q."'";
  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  ?>
```

Here is the problem: When I type only one value in the textbox, it will save in my database multiple times.

EG: I input "Jordan". When I check in my database, it appears as

```
userid 1 J
userid 2 Jo
userid 3 Jor
```

And so on

Comment: I'm confused - what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I don't know what the question is but I will recommend trying out jQuery for beginning AJAX... there are many functions that make it a breeze and take out all the advanced coding involved with doing it from scratch. Check it out: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: If that's the extent of your PHP file, you have some major security problems because you're not validating your input at all. Anyone could hack into your database pretty easily.

Comment: The problem appears that the data is saved into the database multiple times instead of once. At least that's what I get out of this.

Comment: HERE IS THE PROBLEM: When I type in the textbox (only one value). Then it will save on my database. EG: Text i inputed "Jordan". When I check on my database, it will appear: userid 1, J. userid 2, Jo. userid 3 Jor. And so on.

Comment: Jordan, this isn't a forum.  You can always add more information to your original question by editing it (which I have done for you).

Comment: The code it's doing exactly what you make it to do. Maybe you are confused with the onkeypress method. If you want to save the information when the user has finished typing try instead onchange or onblur

Answer (score 5):

onkeypress will fire for EVERY keypress even you do within that box. So here's what happens:

1. You type 'j'
2. showHint() is triggered, sends 'j' to the server
3. The script inserts 'j' into your user table
4. You type 'o', there is now 'jo' in the text field
5. showHint() is triggered, sends 'jo' to the server
6. The script insert 'jo' into your user table
7. etc...

In other words, you're not showing a hint at all, you're just blindly inserting whatever the user types into your database.

If you want to show hints, then you should be doing at LEAST a 'SELECT' query instead and returning the results to your page.

You should also use something like [Mootools](http://mootools.net) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do your AJAX calls. They'll handle the hard parts of building/sending the request for you, without having to worry about what browser the user's using.

As well, read about about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) before releasing a script such as yours out into the wild.

You also have a mal-formed insert query. To insert a new record, the basic syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (field1, field2, field3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

You've got mixed in some sort of partial 'update' query in there, the format of which is

```
UPDATE sometable SET field1=value1, field2=value2, ....
```

I can't see how your query could be inserting anything into the database as it is now, as the syntax is completely broken.

Comment: Regarding the INSERT vs UPDATE syntax, MySQL actually supports multiple, as seen on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending a bit on the browser you use the `onkeypress` event will also fire on keys that do not change the content like the arrow keys, the enter or tab key, F5 to refresh, etc... With some browsers even pressing shift might trigger `onkeypress`. See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) for details.

As your PHP code does not check for the entered value being new it will add the entered value every time you press one of these keys.

Furthermore it *is* a good idea to use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendRequest(str) {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "inputProcess.php?q="+str, true);
 xhttp.send();
}

function showHint(str) {
 if (str.length==0) { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
 } else {
 sendRequest(str)
 }
}
```

I know what you're trying to do please use standard methods...The only issue in your code is actually onKeypressed. You need to call the request when you're sure the user has typed the word completely and is not typing anymore i don't think it's pretty easy in JS you can of course but you have to use a lot of man hours to accomplish.