# how to get parameters in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem, i give two parameters but the php file doesn't manage to get them

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="http://localhost:8090/rest/rest.php?utente="+document.getElementById("utente").value+"&pass="+document.getElementById("pass").value;



    function myFunction(response)
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

and this is the php

```
<?php Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');$utente=$_GET['utente'];$pass=$_GET['pass'];?>
```

enter code here

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not get them"? That PHP code does not do anything with the values...

Comment: Also check your http servers access log file to see what request URL actually gets requested.

Comment: i don't understand, i use xampp

Comment: Before i made a echo with the parameters but they didn't have anything

Comment: You know that xampp is nothing but a distribution of the classical components available in every Linux system? MySQL, PHP and apache http server? You know what a http server is? That it writes log files? How to look at those log files? If not... maybe you should start with the basics first?

Comment: If the `$_GET` super global really does not contain anything, then no GET arguments are sent in the request. That is why I suggested you check the actually requested URL. But only you can do that, we can't.

Comment: do a `print_r($_REQUEST);` to check if there are any variables passed if that's empty then you need to check your URL.

Answer (score 0):

## How send data without refresh using javascript?!

*https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest*

*Similar question : [AJAX HTML PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722932/ajax-html-php-question?rq=1)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="get_data()">Get Data!</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>
    function get_data()
    {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      //http.open("GET","http://test.com/go/to/file.php",true);
      http.open("GET","http://test.com/go/to/file.php?name=test&year=2018",true);
      http.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## How get data parameters using PHP?

You are send request to php file using `GET`.

so parameters is at the URL.

Sample : `http://localhost:8090/rest/rest.php?name=test&year=2018`

rest.php FIle:

```
<?php
//print all of the parameters
print_r($_GET);//you can delete this line
//check name parameter exists or no!
//if(isset($_GET['name']))
if( isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['year']))
{
   echo("Hello ".$_GET['name']);
   echo("(");
   echo($_GET['year']);
   echo(")");
}
else
{
   exit("Error!");
}
```